# prometheus check if a metric is present

Tags: prometheus

I have alerts based on a metric which in my case, sometimes, may disappear. Let's say the metric as `up(env=prod)` and `up(env=staging)`. I have an alert based on the value of this metric. Now, I want to trigger another alert if `up(env='staging')` is not present. I can sum the metric by `env` and look at the value but it does not tell me which env is missing.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do this with `absent(up{env="staging"})`

Comment: posting this because it's counter-intuitive/seems silly, but if you literally want to check if the metric is present, you can use: absent(absent(up{env="staging"}))

Comment: `up{env="staging"}` is sufficient for that.

Answer (score 2):

The [absent](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#absent) function returns non-empty result if the inner [time series selector](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#time-series-selectors) doesn't match any time series. If the series selector matches at least a single time series, then `absent()` returns nothing. For example, if you have the following metrics:

```
up{env="staging"}
up{env="prod"}
```

Then `absent(up)` returns nothing if `up{env="staging"}` stops receiving new samples, while `up{env="prod"}` continues receiving new samples. This means you need to define a separate `absent()` query per each monitored time series:

```
absent(up{env="staging"})
absent(up{env="prod"})
```

This doesn't scale well when the number of monitored time series increases. There is no good generic solution for this issue in Prometheus, but it can be solved with the following single [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html) query in [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/):

```
lag(up[24h]) > 5m
```

This query returns all the `up` time series, which received at least a single sample during the last 24 hours, but didn't receive new samples during the last 5 minutes. See [docs for lag() function](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#lag).