# Checking if all expected results of a Prometheus query are present

Tags: prometheus, promql

Let us assume we have a group of two endpoints which have three services for which the same metrics should be sent to Prometheus. In order to give an example, let us assume in a healthy situation the Prometheus query

```
metric{group="endpoint" service=~"1|2|3"}
```

yields the results

```
metric{id="1", group="endpoint", service="1"}
metric{id="1", group="endpoint", service="2"}
metric{id="1", group="endpoint", service="3"}
metric{id="2", group="endpoint", service="1"}
metric{id="2", group="endpoint", service="2"}
metric{id="2", group="endpoint", service="3"}
```

For an alert I want to check wether all of these metrics are okay. The alert shall be firing if

```
metric{group="endpoint" service=~"1|2|3"} < 1
```

for a predefined duration. What can happen now is that on one endpoint, let's say with id="1", the service "2" is accidentally removed. The problem is that the former query related to the alert won't notice that the service "2" was removed. The only solution I found to still have the alert firing in this situation is the long query

```
metric{group="endpoint" service=~"1|2|3"} < 1 
or count(metric{group="endpoint" service=~"1|2|3"}) != 3*count(up{group="endpoint"}) 
or absent(metric{group="endpoint" service=~"1|2|3"})
```

The absent is needed since if the inner query doesn't find any metric count yields an empty query instead of 0.

**Question**: Is there any more elegant way to achieve this kind of alert rule?

My question is related to [prometheus check if a metric is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51358390/prometheus-check-if-a-metric-is-present) which brought me to the current solution.